# Defining instance AppDomain with Ninject 2?

Tags: .net, dependency-injection, ninject, decorator, appdomain

I create a **ILinkExtractor** instance as follows:

```
void myMethod() {
    AppDomain webDomain = createWebProtectedAppDomain();
    ObjectHandle linkExtractorObj = webDomain.CreateInstanceFrom(assemblyPath, typeof(LinkExtractor).FullName);
    ILinkExtractor linkExtractor = (ILinkExtractor)linkExtractorObj.Unwrap();
    // use it...
    // ...
    // then release the appdomain...
    AppDomain.Unload(webDomain);
}
```

I would like to use this instead, **hiding all the complexity of AppDomain**:

```
void myMethod() {
    ILinkExtractor linkExtractor = kernel.Get<ILinkExtractor>();
    // use it...
    // ...
    // then release (transparently) the appdomain...
}
```

In other words I would like to **use ninject 2 to wrap AppDomain info to my instance** to restrict it for web usage, but this behavior should be hidden by callers.

Is it possible to achieve this behavior using or extending ninject 2?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I would create a `ILinkExtractorManager` that implements `IDisposable` to manage the lifetime of the `ILinkExtractor`.  then use a `using` clause:

```
using( ILinkExtractorManager manager = kernel.Get<ILinkExtractorManager>() )
{
    ILinkExtractor extractor = manager.GetExtractor();

    // usage of extractor

}
```

when the using ends, Dispose() will be called on the manager which can unload the AppDomain at that time.